# Deploy Ablog to github pages

Tags: python, python-sphinx, ablog

I've just started using the [ABlog](http://ablog.readthedocs.org/) plugin for [sphinx](http://sphinx-doc.org/) to create a static-site blog.

Is it easy to change `ablog deploy` to deploy to a different location,
e.g. `../username.github.io/` instead of `./username.github.io/`?

I have my ABlog project under source control in a git repository. Creating my `username.github.io` inside the current ABlog project creates a repo inside a repo and this causes errors (also I don't want to store the built site along with the ABlog repository -- although I could add a `.gitignore`).

Comment: Could someone create a `ablog` tag in Stack Overflow (or does it already exist and I'm missing it?)

Comment: Have you already tried the instructions at http://ablog.readthedocs.org/manual/deploy-to-github-pages/ ?

Comment: Yes (I've also asked the question there) - from the instructions it looks like the location of the deployment folder is always hard-corded to be in the root of the ablog project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it easy to change `ablog deploy` to deploy to a different location,
>   e.g. `../username.github.io/` instead of `./username.github.io/`?

## For ABlog ≥ 0.8.0, yes

For ablog-0.8.0 and above, you can use the `-p` option to specify a github repo location other than the default (`<location of conf.py>/<your username>.github.io`):

```
ablog deploy -p /the/path/for/your/local/github/pages/repo
```

i.e., in your case

```
ablog deploy -p ../username.github.io/
```

#### How to install the most recent ABlog version

Until version 0.8.0 is available on pypi, you can [tell `pip` to install `ablog` directly from git](http://ablog.readthedocs.org/manual/deploy-to-github-pages/#comment-2301946904):

```
pip install git+https://github.com/abakan/ablog.git
```

## For Ablog < 0.8.0, no

For versions prior to 0.8.0, the old version of this answer applies:

> With the current implementation of [ABlog-internal function
>   `ablog_deploy`](https://github.com/abakan/ablog/blob/0ed765d95a23ad7dce48c755773ac60dd08cf319/ablog/commands.py#L308),
>   the location of the target repository cannot be changed:
>
> String `gitdir` (holding the path where the local repository will be
>   created) is [set
>   to](https://github.com/abakan/ablog/blob/0ed765d95a23ad7dce48c755773ac60dd08cf319/ablog/commands.py#L333)
>
> ```
> <confdir>/<github_pages option>.github.io but the `github_pages` option is also [used to choose the remote
> ```
>
> repository](https://github.com/abakan/ablog/blob/0ed765d95a23ad7dce48c755773ac60dd08cf319/ablog/commands.py#L338),
>   so passing something else than the GitHub account name will make the
>   process fail.
>
> Manipulating `confdir` would be difficult and would result in the
>   [configuration
>   file](https://github.com/abakan/ablog/blob/0ed765d95a23ad7dce48c755773ac60dd08cf319/ablog/commands.py#L312)
>   not being found and probably a bunch of other side effects.
>
> However, if you're willing to modify ABlog's source code, it would not
>   be hard to adapt the assignment of `gitdir` as you see fit (maybe
>   introducing another option) to produce the decided effect. (E.g., make
>   it use `confdir` if your new option hasn't been set, and have it use
>   your new option instead if that option has been set.)

Comment: The ablog author has just added a [`-p`](https://github.com/abakan/ablog/commit/cb741637cade0d4f58b3efb1e122ea864d10c145) option to specify a path for use with `ablog deploy`. See discussion [here](http://ablog.readthedocs.org/manual/deploy-to-github-pages/#comment-2301946904). This is available in ablog-0.8.0 and above.